# Android Unable to merge two wave files

Tags: android

I am working in android. I want to merge two wave files and want to create third file. For this I create two input streams and then trying to write those input streams into one output stream file.

**This is my code:-**

```
 File file = new File("/sdcard/z.wav");
        File file1 = new File("/sdcard/zz.wav");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(file1);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();
        long length1 = file1.length();


        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
        byte[] bytes1 = new byte[(int)length1];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < (int)length &&( numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        int offset1 = 0;
        int numRead1 = 0;
        while (offset1 < (int)length1 &&( numRead1=is1.read(bytes1, offset1, bytes1.length-offset1)) >= 0) {
            offset1 += numRead1;
        }





        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("sdcard/guruu.wav");
        Log.v("Trying Activity","before first write");
        fos.write(bytes);

        fos.write(bytes1,0,bytes1.length);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.close();

        is.close();
        is1.close();
```

when I play output file guruu.wav then this only playing file of **file1**, it is not playing content of file2. Please suggest me what mistake I have done. Is any other way to do this ?

I am very new in this so please do not down vote it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not merging the data, you are simply concatenating it.

Thus you end up with one file containing:

- WAV file header for file 1
- audio data for file 1
- WAV file header for file 2
- audio data for file 2

Understandably, when someone reads this file back to play it, they see it as

- WAV file header
- audio data
- some garbage data at the end of the file that they don't even get to consider.

To truly merge these files, you will need to properly consider the [internal structure of  the WAV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV).